# Insert svg file into mosaico mailing

Tags: mosaico

When I try uploading a svg file into a mosaico mailing, I get a message that this file type is not allowed.

Is there a way to change settings, that allows inserting svg files, and maybe other file types?

Answer (score 0):

"Safe File Extensions" can be configured under "/civicrm/admin/options/safe_file_extension?reset=1" - you could probably add .svg there.

This should allow you to upload sch files in CiviCRM. I am however not sure if that configuration also applies to Mosaico and if Mosaico can handle svg-Images.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work for Mosaico!